# android listview multiple views

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with 2 views, one is for the first row and the other is for the rest.

Here is my code in getView:

```
ViewHolder holder = null;

            // if (convertView == null) 
        //   {  
                 holder = new ViewHolder();

                 if(position==0 && category.equalsIgnoreCase("normal"))
                 {
                     convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_featured_list_row, null);                                         
                 } 
                 else
                 {                   
                     convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_row, null);         
                 }      

                     holder.imgItem = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
                     //holder.imgArrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrowImage);
                     holder.txtItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
                     holder.itemValueLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemValueLabel);
                     holder.itemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);                            

                 convertView.setTag(holder);
        //   } 
        //   else 
        //       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
```

The thing is, it will only work this way if I leave it uncommented, but I feel like there is a good reason to check if convertView is null and not re-inflate something already inflated.  But if I uncomment it, it only works on the first load.  Once I refresh the list by updating the array and calling notifydatasetchanged, the first row items ends up multiple times in random locations in my listview.

Answer (score 0):

If you use different layouts then you need to check if you can really reuse `convertView`. You can add a type indicator to your holder and check if the type of convertView is ok to be modified. If not inflate a new View.

```
// check type - use int if you need more than just two layouts.
boolean requiredViewType = (position == 0 && category.equalsIgnoreCase("normal"));

if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag().viewType != requiredViewType) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();

    if (position == 0 && category.equalsIgnoreCase("normal")) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_featured_list_row, null);
    } else {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_row, null);
    }

    holder.imgItem = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
    // holder.imgArrow = (ImageView)
    // convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrowImage);
    holder.txtItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
    holder.itemValueLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemValueLabel);
    holder.itemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);

    // set the type - you obviously need to add that field to ViewHolder
    holder.viewType = requiredViewType;

    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    // etc
}
```